# Por qué no me redirecciona al url/login?

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

estoy realizando un sistema de ventas web (específicamente voy en este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMCjsTKrw94&ab_channel=hdeleon.net)

La cosa es que, al momento de usar la propiedad canActivate, esta se activa pero no redirecciona debidamente, solo me muestra el sitio web en blanco y no entiendo que está mal.

**Modulo de enrutamiento**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ClienteComponent } from './cliente/cliente.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './security/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch:'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'cliente', component: ClienteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**La Clase que activa la redirección**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        
    }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

}
```

**El componente que contiene el URL a seguir en la redirección**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({ templateUrl: 'login.component.html'})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

ngOnInit(){
}
```

Estoy desesperado :c

Answer (score 0):

me parece que tu problema inicial es que estás mezclando dos propiedades dentro de tu archivo de enrutamiento, las propiedades `redirectTo` y `canActivate` podrías intentar, removiendo el `canActivate` si tu objetivo es redirigir